# Заменить в выводе селекта одно число на другое

Tags: sql, select

Добрый день!
Есть селект:

```
SELECT [DISPLAYNAME], COUNT(*) as "Количество"
FROM [table]
group by DISPLAYNAME
```

Получаю таблицу вида:

```
Имя                      Количество
Иванов                            1
Сидоров                           1
```

В этой табличке перечислено количество клиентов, я знаю, что они все уникальные, у всех количестов будет 1шт.

Как сделать, чтобы вместо 1 писался 0, еще одна колонка, тупо заменить 1 на 0? :D
Нужно очень, мне потом суммировать ее с другим селектом, в общем для сравнения нужны тут 1 и 0

Comment: `SELECT [DISPLAYNAME], 0 as "Количество"
FROM [table]
group by DISPLAYNAME`

Comment: `SELECT [DISPLAYNAME], count(*) as "Количество", iif(count(*)  = 1,0,count(*) ) as "OtherCount" FROM [table] group by DISPLAYNAME`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Цитата
>   SELECT [DISPLAYNAME], 0 as "Количество" FROM [table] group by DISPLAYNAME – Mike 12 апр в